# Does any colour appear white to our eyes if its emitted power is extremely large?

Tags: optics, visible-light, photons, vision, lightning

let's consider an ideal monocromatic source (for instance red) and let's assume you can regulate its emitted power without compromising its spectral "finesse".

Start from 0 emitted W/sr. It appears black to our eyes.

Increase the emitted power just a little little bit, still lower than the minimum detectable power of our eye and nervous system. It still appears black despite being physically red (it has a red specific wavelength).

Now, increase the emitted power to a normal level and it will appear red.

Finally, **increase it to an exaggerate value that will almost (like when looking at the sun) blind our eyes. Will it appear white?**

My question starts from the following colour representation which is very common in graphic design:

[image]

Let's consider the maximum saturation (i.e. the boundary of the cylinder). Any wavelength (i.e. hue) becomes white if its lightness increases at maximum level (it is a relative lightness compared to a reference white, if I'm not wrong).

I guess that this kind of representation agrees with physics otherwise it won't make sense for me :( So I was wondering if any colour appears white if its luminance becomes extremely high.

Comment: If the power is extremely large then everything will go black because the light will destroy your retina.... and at intermediate power you will get retinal bleaching and colors will change with the length of exposure. Needless to say it will also hurt a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia says, "The HSL [*hue, saturation, lightness*] representation models the way different paints mix together to create color in the real world." (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) That is to say, it models *subtractive* color mixing, which is different from additive color mixing as in computer displays and, different from how humans perceive colors.

"Lightness" in the HSL model has nothing to do with emitted power or luminance. In subtractive color mixing, "lighter" colors mean less ink is applied, and the lightest possible color is the color that you get by applying *no ink at all* to the presumed-to-be-white paper.